# Выбрать все элементы с одинаковым классом js

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, хочу чтобы всем элементам с одинаковым классом добавлялся класс через js. Но могу сделать так, чтобы работало только для 1 элемента. Думал может надо перебрать, но так не получается. Как можно реализовать? Только без jquery, пожалуйста)

html

```
<button class="intro_btn">Кнопка</button>
<button class="intro_btn">Кнопка</button>
<button class="intro_btn">Кнопка</button>
<button class="intro_btn">Кнопка</button>
<div class="toast">
    test
</div>
```

js

```
const elements = document.querySelector('.intro_btn')
for (let elem of elements) {
    elements.onclick = function() {
        document.querySelector('.toast').classList.add('toast__add');
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.querySelector('.toast').classList.remove('toast__add');
        }, 2500);
    };
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/sk1p96-the-bold/pen/bGvqRvw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо

```
const elements = document.querySelector('.intro_btn')
```

надо

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.intro_btn')
```

а вместо

```
elements.onclick = function() {
```

надо

```
elem.onclick = function() {
```

Comment: Спасибо, все гуд. Вот делал также, но про заменить elements на elem не дошло